# stdout is accessible to user but not from su - user

Tags: permissions, su, stdout

I'm testing redirecting programs std_out to /dev/stdout in docker alpine.
I can't figure out why I can echo from user to stdout, but not from `su` command.

`docker exec -it 779ddea6ec33 bash`  # root user

```
bash-4.4# su - http -c "echo 1 >> /dev/stdout"
-sh: can't create /dev/stdout: Permission denied 
# why comman above failed
bash-4.4# whoami 
root
bash-4.4# su - root -c "echo 1 >> /dev/stdout"
1
```

`docker exec -u http -it 779ddea6ec33 bash` # http user

```
bash-4.4$ whoami 
http
bash-4.4$ echo 1 >> /dev/stdout
1
# but this command works
```

some ls:

```
bash-4.4# ls -lad /dev/stdout 
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            15 Jul  7 16:47 /dev/stdout -> /proc/self/fd/1
bash-4.4# ls -lad /proc/self/fd/1
lrwx------    1 root     root            64 Jul  7 18:09 /proc/self/fd/1 -> /dev/pts/0
bash-4.4# ls -lad /dev/pts/0 
crw--w----    1 root     tty       136,   0 Jul  7 18:09 /dev/pts/0
```

stat:

```
bash-4.4# stat /dev/stdout
  File: '/dev/stdout' -> '/proc/self/fd/1'
  Size: 15              Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   symbolic link
Device: 4dh/77d Inode: 8013573     Links: 1
Access: (0777/lrwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2019-07-07 18:09:33.000000000
Modify: 2019-07-07 16:47:08.000000000
Change: 2019-07-07 16:47:08.000000000

bash-4.4# stat /dev/pts/0
  File: /dev/pts/0
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 1024   character special file
Device: 4eh/78d Inode: 3           Links: 1     Device type: 88,0
Access: (0620/crw--w----)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    5/     tty)
Access: 2019-07-07 18:15:28.000000000
Modify: 2019-07-07 18:15:28.000000000
Change: 2019-07-07 17:48:22.000000000
```

Comment: You're trying to open a file for writing (a special file, but a file nonetheless), that's owned by another user and probably doesn't have write access to everybody. What did you expect?

Comment: That doesn't explain why it doesn't fail in the 2nd case.

Comment: What's to explain there? You're opening a file that's owned and writable by you.

Comment: In both 1st and 2nd cases, it's not owned by me. Why it doesn't fail in 1st case? I don't own that file in 1st case. I run the command from `http` user.

Comment: How do you know it's not owned by you? Have you ran `stat` on it?

Comment: I added ls to my question. The file is NOT owned by http

Comment: [There are 2 of them, how comes you only see one? Just click on me](https://static.pychat.org/photo/8SDkiTo9_.png)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwBcq.png <- I see only output of `ls` from only one session. Where's the other? And the output of `stat`, which is what I asked for?And `stat -L` as well.

Comment: Oh thank you, I didn't think that docker will change the devices stats according to the user I logged in... If you post your answer I will accept it.

Comment: Since your Q was **not** tagged [linux] it's worth noting that this behavior is very *linux specific*; on all the other Unix systems which implement `/dev/stdout`, `/dev/fd/`, etc, you can open & write to `/dev/stdout` if you can write to fd 1, period. Opening `/dev/stdout` will dup the process's stdout, instead of trying to re-open the original inode through a magic symlink as it does on linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/dev/stdout` is a special file.

Lets say I'm logged in with two user (user1 on tty1 and user2 on tty2).

`/dev/stdout` for user1 refers to `/dev/tty1` and for user two refers to `/dev/tty2`.

Here `http` user is trying to write something on `/dev/stdout` which belongs to current user (root):

```
bash-4.4# su - http -c "echo 1 >> /dev/stdout"
-sh: can't create /dev/stdout: Permission denied
```

In the other case `http` is writing to a file which it owns.

Comment: It's not the writing that's the problem - it's trying to open it again for writing (via redirection). It already has an inherited fd to the same file that it can write to without problems.

Comment: If it is possible for you I would love to see a complete answer on this question ...

Comment: This is answer is fine, just correct that bit.